# Save user input as xml file in the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, file, save, paperclip

I have a form_tag on a "Stream" model which accepts user input as show below:

```
<%= form_tag('/generate_xml', :method=>'post') do %>
 <p>
 Content:<br />
   <%= text_field_tag "content" %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

The generate_xml action is as below:

```
def generate_xml
 @content = params[:content]
 builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
 xml.streams {
  xml.content {
   xml.name { xml.text @content }
  }
 }
 end

 file = File.new('dir.xml','w')
 file.puts builder.to_xml
 file.close
end
```

While I can generate a file **dir.xml** I *do not want this file to be stored locally but in the database directly*.How can I do this? I so far have tried generating file-related columns in the "Stream" model(where I want to store the xml files) using paperclip but I stuck about how I can generate a file on the fly and save it to database.

Comment: Why don't you just store it in a field in your database table?

Comment: @ipd : You mean store the xml as a string? Because Rails does not have a file ActiveRecord datatype

Comment: Yes, why not? See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the xml content as a string.

So, do a rails migration to add the string column to your table.

```
rails g model UserContent xml:string
```

Then just store it as a string in there:

```
uc = UserContent.create(:xml => builder.to_xml)
```

Comment: Thank you. A correction on your answer. An instance of the model should be created i.e. `@usercontent=UserContent.new` and you cannot call attributes directly on the model itself.

Comment: doh.  I must have been distracted when i wrote that, rewrote in a better fashion.

Comment: @ipd what's the benefit of choose xml vs text? It seems you are given back a string anyways

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh in my example `xml` is just the name of the column  passed to Rails generate command, yes it is stored in the database as a String and the column is defined as such.